# Android: Creating notification inside service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have problems creating a notification inside a **service** and showing it in status bar...

This is how I created my notification in activity:

```
    int NOTIFY_ID=100;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Grafik.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("Message")
            .setContentText("Hello world");
    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

But I when i put this code inside my service it crashes, and I think that the problems are here

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Grafik.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and here

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

but I don't know why...

Comment: Post your stack trace showing the exception, and indicate which lines of code shown above are represented in that trace.

Comment: I solved id, all I had to do is to create it in a new void method o.O
but I was wondering if I want to add sound, I have to add it as uri, right? so where do I put it in my project and how to reference it?

Comment: what method you created? I'm having the same problem :(